# PBS error while using zsh

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run some Python code on a cluster that uses PBS. The script is

```
#!/bin/zsh
#PBS -N JobTitle
#PBS -q QName
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=48:mpiprocs=48
#PBS -l walltime=10:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o output.txt
#PBS -p 1023

python3 models.py
```

However the output is

```
pbs_mom, exec of /bin/zsh failed with error: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: And is `zsh` installed on the system with the interpreter stored in `/bin`?

Comment: Yes, `zsh 5.0.2` is installed on the master node which I am working from.